# docstring of dynamic module attribute

Tags: python, docstring

I have dynamic module attributes, which are `functools.partial` constructor of the module's class (`Filter`). The attributes themselves work as intended, but if possible I'd like to improve how `help` displays their docstrings.

Here is my `__getattr__` function of this module `fgb`:

```py
def __getattr__(name):

    # [snip] filter name checking (returns AttributeError if not valid)

    func = partial(Filter, name)
    func.__name__ = name
    # call FFmpeg (subprocess) to retrieve the filter info help text
    func.__doc__ = path.ffmpeg(
        f"-hide_banner -h filter={name}", universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE
    ).stdout

    return func
```

Now, if I call help, say for a crop filter:

```py
help(fgb.crop)
```

it displays the docstring text as intended, but it starts with:

```
Help on partial:

crop = functools.partial(<class 'ffmpegio.filtergraph.Filter'>, 'crop')
    ...
```

Is there a way to make it print something along the line of the following?

```
Help on crop:

crop(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, it's a lot simpler than I made it out to be. The following seems to work:

```py
def __getattr__(name):

    # [snip] filter name checking (returns AttributeError if not valid)

    def func(*args,**kwargs):
        return Filter(name, *args, **kwargs)

    func.__name__ = name
    # call FFmpeg (subprocess) to retrieve the filter info help text
    func.__doc__ = path.ffmpeg(
        f"-hide_banner -h filter={name}", universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE
    ).stdout

    return func
```